# Copy and rename with date and timestamp only if it was modified

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I am trying to backup a file whenever it is modified. I tried using 
    xcopy "source" dest" /D /Y
This works in the sense it only copies the file over if it has been modified, but I want to add a timestamp if it has been modified so I keep all version changes of a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by checking the archive bit

- to get the LastWriteTime in a locale/user settings independent way and perform the copy I use PowerShell as a tool
- to avoid perpetually creating copies of the copy files containing `_20` are dropped.
- the archive bit of the original file is reset.

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\01\25\SU_1398203.cmd
@Echo off
set "Files=*.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B/A:A "%Files%" 2^>Nul ^| find /V "_20"') Do (
    powershell -Nop -C "Get-Item '%%A' | Copy-Item -Destination {$_.FullName -replace '(?=%%~xA)',('_{0:yyyMMddHHmmss}' -f $_.LastWriteTime)}"
    attrib -A "%%A"
)
```

Sample result with a `yyyyMMddHHmmss` stamp:

```
> attrib *.txt
                     Q:\Test\2019\01\25\log.txt
A                    Q:\Test\2019\01\25\log_20190125145024.txt
                     Q:\Test\2019\01\25\ref.txt
A                    Q:\Test\2019\01\25\ref_20190125150510.txt
```